# TorchMetrics correct way to log MetricCollection

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm wondering how to best log a MetricCollection in pytorch lightning. The [docs](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/overview.html) show the following code for logging MetricCollections (which seems to be outdated, since `validation_epoch_end` does not exist in lightning >2.0)

```
from torchmetrics import MetricCollection
from torchmetrics.classification import MulticlassAccuracy, MulticlassPrecision, MulticlassRecall

class MyModule(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        metrics = MetricCollection([
            MulticlassAccuracy(num_classes), MulticlassPrecision(num_classes), MulticlassRecall(num_classes)
        ])
        self.train_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix='train_')
        self.valid_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix='val_')

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        logits = self(x)
        # ...
        output = self.train_metrics(logits, y)
        # use log_dict instead of log
        # metrics are logged with keys: train_Accuracy, train_Precision and train_Recall
        self.log_dict(output)

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        logits = self(x)
        # ...
        self.valid_metrics.update(logits, y)

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        # use log_dict instead of log
        # metrics are logged with keys: val_Accuracy, val_Precision and val_Recall
        output = self.valid_metric.compute()
        self.log_dict(output)
```

There also seems to be missing a `self.valid_metric.reset()` call in the above code snippet, as indicated in [this part](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/lightning.html) of the logs, so overall not sure how reliable the docs are for this example.

What I'd like to know is whether I can log the MetricCollection object directly, as I could do with a simple `Metric` object. Something like

```
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    logits = self(x)
    ...
    self.valid_metric(logits, y)
    self.log_dict(self.valid_metric, on_step=True, on_epoch=True)
```

I tried that, but it resulted in a

```
"Could not find the `LightningModule` attribute for the `torchmetrics.Metric` logged. You can fix this by setting an attribute for the metric in your `LightningModule`."
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there no support for logging `MetricCollection` objects directly?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is much safer to return the metric output and log them by yourself. For instance:

```
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    logits = self(x)
    ...
    met_out = self.valid_metric(logits, y)
    self.log_dict(met_out, on_step=True, on_epoch=True)
```

In my developing environment, I don't update PyTorch-lightning or TorchMetrics regularly. They appear to change variable name and the way of using their supporting methods frequently. So, it is better to remain old-fashion.